# Insert a sequence of numbers into SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to initialize an Android SQLite database that will contain selected categoryId's (integers from 0 to MAX_CAT_ID). I want to insert all possible Ids to begin with.

Is there a way to do this via SQL? I cannot generate the string (see example below) because I need the 'query' String variable to be static.

For example:

```
String query = "insert into validCategories (catId) values (0 to " + MAX_CAT_ID + ")";
```

Thanks!

Comment: AFAIK there is not a maximum number of _ids, and if there is, entering them at the beginning will just make the database larger than it needs to be. Not to mention, if any row is deleted, that rows +id will be deleted too.

Comment: I think I didn't explain myself correctly. Lets say I have 5 categories. So I want to prepopulate the table with something like "insert into validCategories (catId) values (0,1,2,3,4)". However I want it to depend on MAX_CAT_ID, in case this value ever increases the SQL will still work. In this case the catId column is not the primary key.

Comment: ahhh, you don't mean the _id that has to be the first column in the database, but instead an ID column you specify, right?

Comment: Have you though about using a separate table for each categories?

Comment: Oh, thought I had you there. Here it goes again: I have N categories: cat[0] = "Colors"; ... cat[N-1] = "Places";, etc. They are just a few, and I have to keep them as an array (cannot store the actual names in a DB). These categories can be selected/deselected by the user. For data persistance purposes, I want to keep the category index (or what I'm calling the "Id") of the categories that have been selected in a DB. The first time the app runs I want to fill the DB table with all the possible index values of cat[x], so all will be "selected" by default. Does this make sense?

Comment: I get what you mean, and I don't think that functionality is available. Could you generate a string `PART_OF_QUERY` being `"(0,1,2,...,MAX_CAT_ID)"` and then construct `query` as `"insert into ... values " + PART_OF_QUERY` ? Then it would still be static.

Comment: Well that will work, but it's not the kind of solution I was hoping for. Oh well! Thanks!